# How do I get one individual modal pop-up to display at a time?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, popup

I need a little jQuery help. I have a number of individual product divs (**.productsWrap**) displaying on a page all with a hidden infomation section. The idea is that when **a.activator** for a particular product is clicked a semi-opaque overlay (**.productsOverlay**) drops down and is followed by the info section for that particular product (**.productsPopBox**). There might be ten **.productsWrap**s on the page so I only want one of the pop-ups to display at a time.

In short, if somebody clicks **a.activator** for a given product (.productsWrap) then **.productsOverlay** and **.productsPopBox** will appear for that product only.

The HTML markup is:

```
<section class="productsWrap">
   <section class="blueHeader"><h2></h2></section>
   <article>
      <div class="productsText">
          <a class="activator">Full service details</a>
      </div>
   </article>
</section>

<div class="productsOverlay overlay" style="display:none;"></div>
<div class="productsPopBox popBox" >
    <h2></h2><span class="close">x</span>
</div>
```

And this is my bad attempt at the jQuery: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rXNKU/5/)

My first attempt sort of worked. It looked good insofar as the pop-up actually did something and the effects looked nice. However, it caused all of the **.productsOverlay** and **.productsPopBox** for all of the **.productsWrap** to drop down at the same time.

```
$('.activator').click(function(){
    $('.productsOverlay, .caseStudiesOverlay').fadeIn('fast',function(){
        $('.productsPopBox, .caseStudiesPopBox').animate({'top':'-150px'},500);
    });
});
$('.productsOverlay, .caseStudiesOverlay, span.close').click(function(){
    $('.productsPopBox, .caseStudiesPopBox').animate({'top':'-1000px'},500,function(){
       $('.productsOverlay, .caseStudiesOverlay').fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: If I understand correctly what you want you should probably take a look at a jquery notification plugin such as [noty](http://needim.github.io/noty/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was hoping to do this without a plugin.

For an actual functioning example, I've based my work on the following [Link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444694/hide-show-toggle-separate-divs-with-the-same-class-name

The problem is that the example doesn't work with jquery 1.9.1

Comment: Alright, now I see what you actually want to accomplish. Are you open to using jQuery UI? If so, take a look at [the accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/).

Comment: Perhaps! The problem is that I'm probably back at the foot of the problem - my understanding of jq/ js is so deficient that I might not be able to figure it out :( Still, I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't solved the issue you were having, here's a modified version of what you had in your linked jsfiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/exafred/rXNKU/50/)

I wasn't sure if you were going for a "one modal popup for all products, with the popup content changing based on the product that was clicked" or "each product has its own popup".

If it's the former, you should be able to replace the click event for a.activator with:

```
$('.activator').click(function (e) {
    $('.productsOverlay, .popupClose, .productsPopBox').fadeOut(250);
    var wrapper = $(this).parents('.wrap');
    var html = $(this).siblings('.hiddenDetails').html();
    wrapper.children('.productsOverlay, .popupClose').fadeIn(250)
        .siblings('.productsPopBox').html(html).fadeIn(250);
});
```

And only the current product's overlay would be displayed.

It's (very) rough, but I'm sure that just means it's good to build on, right?